# Loading and rendering a .ecw raster with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, ecw

I am trying to load an .ecw file with pyqgis on a pc. Usin version 2.14 of QGIS. I tried the code i could find in the [cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/index.html) about [loading](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers) and rendering [raster](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html) from it I interpred this code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\some\path')
file = 'FooBar.ecw'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(file)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(file, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load again!"
else:
    print rlayer.renderer()
    print rlayer.renderer().type()
    if hasattr(rlayer, "setCacheImage"):
        rlayer.setCacheImage(None)
    rlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

I will get a dialog window where I get to define the projection for the raster. But th file will not draw.
The file is fully functionall to load normally. How can I make the raster draw with pyqgis?

Comment: Try using `qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("/path/to/raster", "any_name")` to load the raster to the map registry. I think what you are doing is just accessing the raster but not loading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost done! As @Joseph correctly suggested, you only need to load the raster to the map registry.

There was also a missing `import` in the code.

The following code should work for you:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\some\path')
file = 'FooBar.ecw'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(file)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(file, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load again!"
else:
    print rlayer.renderer()
    print rlayer.renderer().type()
    if hasattr(rlayer, "setCacheImage"):
        rlayer.setCacheImage(None)
    rlayer.triggerRepaint()

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```